# AI integration with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, artificial-intelligence

I have been programming in rails for quite sometime now.
Now what I want to do is to integrate AI and Rails.
I essentially want to make independent agents.
I am asking this question for rails but I have no experience of agent based programming(hope the term is right !) and any resource pointed out will be highly appreciated.
Basically what i want to do is make a simple simulation where there are rounds.
There is a player in each round and has to take some decisions.
I want to build agents who along with the player act as his/her competitors and take decisions.SO in each round, i want to have 5 players.1 is a human and other 4 agents.
I would like somebody to guide me to how to start.
any resources for the same will be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks sir But I want to start from the basics instead of using a gem.
By the way the gem looks very interesting and thanks for pointing !

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, i have no experience about AI using ruby, but i found a online book that give you AI implementation using ruby, check it out. http://www.markwatson.com/opencontent/ruby_ai/book.html

Comment: I would also like some help on AI programming like...where do I start ??

Comment: what about neural network, soft computing... it's basic need for learning AI